# How to remove specific session in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am facing a problem. I have created two sessions:

1. `Session["userid"] = UserTbl.userid;`
2. `Session["userType"] = UserTbl.type;`

I know how to remove sessions using `Session.clear()`. I want to remove the session "userType".

How do I remove a specific session?

Comment: try set Null to Session["userType"]

Comment: What about Session.Remove("userType");

Comment: This user's nomenclature is a bit wrong here; they talk about remove "sessions", but really they want to remove a session variable.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is nothing like session container , so you can set it as null

but rather you can set individual session element as null or ""

like `Session["userid"] = null;`

Comment: When I hit back it just loads up the main page even though the session is gone.

Answer (score 85):

```
Session.Remove("name of your session here");
```

Comment: @RezaRahmati i would like to know the answer to this as well

Comment: @WhatsThePoint It seems it is, by default there is reader/writer lock on it
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx

Answer (score 32):

you can use Session.Remove() method; [Session.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.remove.aspx)

```
Session.Remove("yourSessionName");
```

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to nullify session in ASP.NET. Session in essence is a cookie, set on client's browser and in ASP.NET, its name is usually `ASP.NET_SessionId`. So, theoretically if you delete that cookie (which in terms of browser means that you set its expiration date to some date in past, because cookies can't be deleted by developers), then you loose the session in server. Another way as you said is to use `Session.Clear()` method. But the best way is to set another irrelevant object (usually `null` value) in the session in correspondance to a key. For example, to nullify `Session["FirstName"]`, simply set it to `Session["FirstName"] = null`.

Answer (score 2):

> HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("sessionname");

it works for me

Answer (score 1):

A single way to remove sessions is setting it to null;

```
Session["your_session"] = null;
```