# Session.Remove("session_variable"); not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Hi in the following stuff am trying to remove the session after completing the certain tasks. but the session.remove() not working here.

```
if (Session["CaseNumber"] != "" || Session["CaseNumber"] != null)
        {
            casenumber = Session["CaseNumber"].ToString();
            guid = Session["guid"].ToString();
            _duration = bal.viewServiceActivity(guid);
            case1 = bal.viewCaseDetail(casenumber);
            dt = bal.getRelatedNotes(guid);
            Session.Remove("CaseNumber");
            Session.Remove("guid");

        }
        else
        {
            casenumber = Session["searchCase"].ToString();
            guid = Session["caseGuid"].ToString();
            _duration = bal.viewServiceActivity(guid);
            case1 = bal.viewCaseDetail(casenumber);
            dt = bal.getRelatedNotes(guid);
            Session.Remove("searchCase");
            Session.Remove("caseGuid");
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove specific session in asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971625/how-to-remove-specific-session-in-asp-net)

Comment: You can refer this [Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8971674/2123679

Thanks

Comment: I have tried all ways but nothing happen.

Comment: How do you know "it's not working"? What are you checking, how and when are you doing it?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing really wrong with portion of your code shown above. Just understanding is required about how it works.

`Session.Remove(key)` removes memory used for the key in the session dictionary. When using  second approach of : `Session["searchCase"]=null;` , the key will still exist in the Session although the value is null.

Try setting the `Session["Key_Name"]` to `null`. For example:

```
if (Session["CaseNumber"] != "" || Session["CaseNumber"] != null)
            {
                casenumber = Session["CaseNumber"].ToString();
                guid = Session["guid"].ToString();
                _duration = bal.viewServiceActivity(guid);
                case1 = bal.viewCaseDetail(casenumber);
                dt = bal.getRelatedNotes(guid);
                Session["CaseNumber"] = null; // Set NULL
                Session["guid"] = null; // Set NULL

            }
```

**`Session.Remove()` doesn't destroys the object bypassing all basic .net rules of object referencing and memory management.** What you need to understand here is that `Session.Remove()` does exactly what it suggests:  It removes the reference to the object from its internal collection. Nothing more to expect.

If you need something destroyed, you need to implement `IDisposable`, and furthermore, you may instruct the garbage collector to collect if you are in a hurry  using `GC.Collect()`.

Check this SO question: [Proper use of the IDisposable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface)

[Microsoft Forum](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/abb22957-2ec4-4ef5-b6a2-4e3f3301d9fc/sessionremovekey-doesnt-actually-work) confirms the same.

It seems more like an optimization OR so called standard way of implementation.
When you remove an object it is 'marked for removal' but not really removed...unless space is required.
It's how garbage collection works.  Just because an object goes out of scope doesn't mean it's destructor gets called and the memory freed immediately.  May be `GC` can remove an object much later.

**Still, as a last check, do this** :

Make sure you are not viewing a cached version of the page, or you don't add the item to the Session object again somewhere in your application.