# I want to know how Session.Clear () works on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, session

`Session.Clear ();` Does this empty all session on asp.net? Can I delete a specific session, such as `Session["USER_ID"].Remove()`? Or `session["USER_ID"].Clear ();`

Comment: You might wanna read the documentation about [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#session-state)

Comment: I got it thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Session.Clear ();`  Removes all keys and values from the session-state collection.

`Session.Remove();` remove values in session state

> There are many ways to nullify session in ASP.NET. Session in essence
> is a cookie, set
>
> on client's browser and in ASP.NET, its name is usually
> `ASP.NET_SessionId`. So,
>
> theoretically if you delete that cookie (which in terms of browser
> means that you set
>
> its expiration date to some date in past, because cookies can't be
> deleted by
>
> developers), then you loose the session in server. Another way as you
> said is to use
>
> `Session.Clear()` method. But the best way is to set another
> irrelevant object
>
> (usually null value) in the session in correspondance to a key. For
> example, to
>
> nullify `Session["FirstName"]`, simply set it to `Session["FirstName"] = null`.

see this link
[How to remove specific session in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971625/how-to-remove-specific-session-in-asp-net)

also this link can help you
[What is the difference between Session.Abandon() and Session.Clear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470445/what-is-the-difference-between-session-abandon-and-session-clear)

Comment: Please specify the source of your citation.

Answer (score 0):

`Session.Clear()` can be used if you want that the user remaining in the same session (prevent him from doing relogin) and just reset all of his session specific data. The reason for that is because `Session.Clear()` **Removes all the keys and values from the session-state collection**. It actually removes all values from the Object. The session with the same key is still alive.

By the way, the `Session.Abandon()` **removes all the objects** stored in a Session.

So, if you use Session.Abandon(), you lose that specific session and the user will get a new session key. You could use it for example when the user logs out.

Check out this article for more info - http://csharpexample.com/CsharpExampleSeeDetail.aspx?Did=78&CatID=29

Comment: `Session.Abandon()` is not in .net core.